# String passed through Django is undefined in JavaScript but renders fine

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

In Django, I am passing an array of strings ['A', 'B', 'C'] to the view and hoping to use these with a JavaScript script I have on the page.

However, even though I am able to display the contents in HTML, when I try use them in JavaScript like such:

```
{% for l in labs %}
console.log({{ l }})
{% endfor %}
```

I get an error that 'Reference Error A is undefined' which I cannot comprehend. How is it possible if it is undefined when clearly by referencing the value it is infact defined?

Comment: Try `console.log("{{ l }}")` then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l` will render as its literal value. But JavaScript doesn't know what that value means. You need to wrap it in quotes.

```
console.log("{{ l }}")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Is there an equivalent to handle the whole array in one go? i.e. "{{ l }}" would be an array? Or, would I need to loop through this one by one to convert?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean; this would work fine with an array.